# I want to make a windows application which playes video from net. By Buffering. in C#.net

Tags: c#, video-streaming

I am Trying to develop a windows app/sw in C#.net Which have different buttons and a Video player. I am using Windows Media Player Tool as Player.
Let me Explain what i need.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
player.URL = @"http://ads.yldmgrimg.net/apex/mediastore/5648e278-a76b-4294-9268-3dbd9c6a861a";
player.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

Above is a code of button1_click. 'player' is a name of Windows Media Player Tool.
when i click on this button it buffers the video from given path and played it in my player.
But the problem is, when i upload a video of my own in my own storage place and give a link of that video like

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
player.URL = @"http://www.youthsoft.in/aa/Khwabon%20(Force)%20(www.DJMaza.Com).avi";
player.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

then it starts downloading the whole video and then it playes. But I need it like it buffers some part and play and again buffer a part and play.
This is my 1st time i am dealing with this kind of project. Please Give a detailed solution as in form of Code, some Tutorials or any else that helps me to understand this procedure.
after this I also want to know how to encode and decode video, and where does my player stores its buffered video in temp files and etc..
Thank you.
Salil Malek